# what are the things I have to do regularly on ubuntu to stay up to date

Tags: kernel, updates, security, maintenance

What do you recommend an average home or office user (provided they also have root access to the machine they're using) do on a daily/weekly/monthly/yearly basis or so to keep their system clean, fast, up-to-date, secure, slim, etc.?

I'm looking for things like

```
apt-get update; apt-get upgrade
```

or purging of old kernels and so on.

Comment: The great thing about Linux is that it doesn't tend to slow down over time as Windows does

Comment: 'Getting rid of old kernels' is already automatic in 16.04 and newer, unless you have deactivated the feature.

Comment: @user535733 you sure? it's not in mines ...

Comment: @Ravexina you have likely either deactivated unattended-upgrade, or you have otherwise made kernel packages ineligible for autoremoval. Could be a change apt-marking, could be a dependency, could be a couple possibilities. But for most users (including all my test systems), kernel autoremoval works properly. I'll happily triage the bug for 'my kernels won't autoremove' if *anyone* can explain how to duplicate it.

Comment: @user535733 I have to test it in full desktop installations, cause most of my systems are installed via network installer and they don't come with `unattended-upgrade` at all.

Comment: @Ravexina not having u-u installed at all would certainly block automatic autoremoval!

Comment: This type of question really depends on each individual user's purpose. Things that average user does regularly are different from what a system administrator might do, and what software developer might do. Too broad of a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do these stuff manually just like I do:

Always keep your sources up to date using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

use `sudo apt-get upgrade` regularly to upgrade all packages to newer versions, get security updates and patches.

use:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to get install new kernel, it might remove or install new packages if it was necessary.

time to time use:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to clear your `apt` cache, it removes old `deb` files which are not necessary anymore.

and run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to remove old kernels or packages that are not necessary anymore like dependencies which are not being used anymore.

that's what I do.

If you use `apt` instead of `apt-get` then by running `apt upgrade` you get all packages updates also new kernel and you don't even have to run `apt autoclean` cause it's not going to cache `deb` files.

---

You should also have backup from your system's important paths:

```
/etc
/var
/home
```

are the places which I always keep a backup of them.